# Unresolved attribute reference 'objects'

Tags: python, django

In models.py I have class Memo:

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    MonthName = models.ForeignKey(Months, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ProjectName = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Hours = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ProjectManager = models.ForeignKey(ItEmployee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.MonthName) + ' - ' + str(self.ProjectName)
```

In views.py I am getting warning Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class Memo:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from History.models import Memo

def memos(request):
    all_memos = Memo.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for memo in all_memos:
        url = '/memo/' + str(Memo.MonthName) + '/'
        html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + Memo.ProjectName + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: so is the field .objects present for each instance or for the entire class Memo? As the answer below mentions, the confusion most likely comes from differentiating between the class Memo and instances (memo)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the uppercase `Memo` in your for loop, referring to the class as a whole instead of the `memo` instances in `all_memos`. Try this:

```
for memo in all_memos:
    url = '/memo/' + str(memo.MonthName) + '/'
    html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + memo.ProjectName + '</a><br>'
```

As an aside, your model attributes would conventionally be written as `month_name`, `project_name` etc. vs `MonthName`, `ProjectName`, etc.

Comment: It seems like @Yopa was having an issue with the line containing Memo.objects.all(). Wouldn't they still have the issue with that line?

Comment: The issue was certainly with trying to access `Memo.MonthName` rather than `memo.MonthName` (same for `ProjectName`). The original poster was trying to access an instance-level attribute on a reference to the class, rather than on the instance itself.